# Addinf event listeners for Dynamically added elements - HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to add event listeners for HTML elements which have been dynamically added using JavaScript.
Something like
I have a div in my main page

```
<div id="someid"></div>
```

and on click of a button with its eventlistener as

```
document.getElementById("someid").innerHTML = "<input type='button' id ='ad' value='Add' style='height:30px; width:90px'/>"
document.getElementById("ad").onclick = notherFunc;
```

and that function is like

```
function notherFunc(){
      alert("WORKING")
}
```

But it isn't working. Is there any way to bind that button with a function?

Comment: Your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/46/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a technique called "[event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)". Essentially, you need to bind the click handler to the element that does exists and see if the element that was clicked is the element you were expecting.

```
document.getElementById("someid").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    if (e.target.id === "ad") {
        notherFunc();
    }

});
```